# What if Hilbert's 10th problem (finding integer roots of polynomials) did not have the integrality requirement

Tags: polynomials

Hilbert's 10th problem is to devise an algorithm that tells us whether a given arbitrary polynomial has integer roots, and we know that this is undecidable. But what if there was no requirement that the roots are integer? how would it be solved then ? if there is a solution in that case, then why does this not imply a solution to the integer case (i.e., solve and check if the roots happen to be integer) ?
Thank you,

Comment: What do you mean by "no requirement that the roots are integers"? If you don't specify where you are looking for roots, you might trivialize the problem. For example, over an algebraically closed field every polynomial has a solution.

Comment: All polynomials over a field have roots in the algebraic closure of that field.. the restriction is more interesting than the more general case. We know, for instance, that all polynomials with coefficients in $\Bbb C$ have roots in $\Bbb C$. We also know that all fields have an algebraic closure.

Comment: "solve and check if the roots happen to be integer": though this seems trivial at first sight, it is not as there is no method to solve general polynomials analytically.

Answer (score 2):

The similar question for the rational solutions is an open problem. See [HILBERT'S TENTH PROBLEM: What can we do with Diophantine equations?](http://HILBERT'S%20TENTH%20PROBLEM:%20What%20can%20we%20do%20with%20Diophantine%20equations?)
For other generalizations see [Hilbert's Tenth Problem over rings of number-theoretic interest](http://math.mit.edu/~poonen/papers/aws2003.pdf).

Answer (score 2):

Maybe it will help to consider a specific example.  Let's consider the equation $$x^2 + y^2 = z^2.$$

Solving this over the real numbers is straightforward.  We can pick any $x$ and $y$ that we like, any $x$ and $y$ at all, and then:  $$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$  Now we have a solution of the equation.
For example, one solution takes $x=3$ and $y=\frac{17}{12}$ and then $z = \sqrt{\frac{1585}{144}} \approx 3.32$.  Easy.
(There is a minor side condition:  $x^2+y^2$ must not be negative.  But it never is negative, so we can forget about it.)

Now let's consider the same equation over the integers.  Again we pick any integers $x$ and $y$ that we like, and the equation will have the same solution:

$$z = \sqrt{x^2+y^2}.$$

**But but but**! There is another condition: $z$ must be an integer.   Which it is, only if $x^2+y^2$ is a perfect square.  So the question is now “When is $x^2 + y^2$ a perfect square?”  Which is no different from the original question.  Here the issue is that while the square root of a (non-negative) real number is real, the square root of an integer is not always an integer.

Unlike the real-numbers situation, $x^2 + y^2 = z^2$ does not have a solution for every choice of $x$ and $y$.  For $x=2$ there are no solutions; for $x=20$ there are exactly three. (I think.)  With some work we can figure out the complete answer, which is quite interesting, much moreso than the answer for real numbers, where the problem is simple.

Now let's consider a similar example:

$$x^3 + y^3 = z^3.$$

This equation looks very similar to the previous, and over the real numbers, the solution is very similar.  We can choose any $x$ and any $y$ we like, and then $$z = \sqrt[3]{x^3+y^3}.$$

Over the integers, though, the $\sqrt[3]{}$ operation is not guaranteed to produce an integer $z$ unless $x^3 + y^3$ is a perfect cube.  When does this happen?  Only when $xy=0$, it turns out.

The equations look similar, and over the reals the solutions are similar, but over the integers the solutions are completely different.  The requirement of integrality makes a big difference.

Comment: Perfect, thanks. The examples you gave focus on the case in which you can easily isolate the last variable. In general after you assign all but one variable you can still be left with an arbitrary polynomial over a single variable. But this is indeed known to be solvable over the reals.

Comment: Quite so.  I drafted a second section explaining why this is; it depends on two properties that the real numbers have that the integers don't: they are dense and complete.  These properties enable all sorts of techniques for approximating solutions, or for narrowing down intervals in which solutions might appear, until we find the actual solutions.  The abstract versions of these techniques become arguments that solutions must exist.  None of these techniques and arguments work over the integers. Consider the intermediate value theorem, for example.